# What is the wiring for a patch cable?

Tags: networking, cable

What is the wiring order for an 10/100/n-Base-T patch cable?
What about a crossover (x-over) cable?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image]

Doing a google image search for "cat5 pinouts" has plenty of others as well

Comment: Note than in an era of auto-polarity-detecting switches crossover cables to go from switch to switch are no longer always necessary :)

Comment: Yes, but you can you guanentee that auto-polarity mode will be supported/enabled on that device? no you can't so there for its better to learn both T568 A&B so that you can make them if need arises.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great guide right [here](http://www.pcmobilehelp.com/support/cat5WiringDiagram.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This is really one where google just has the answers http://www.google.com/search?q=wire+network+cable  A patch cable is just a straight through cable